# Blackjack program, having issues with dealer recognizing Ace value [python]

Tags: python, blackjack

Hey guys when playing blackjack, the dealer will know that ace can be 1 or 11, but when the opportunity comes for it to play it as 1, it busts. For instance:

Start off with 2 aces, you technically have either a 2, a 12, or a 22.

Lets say the first card the dealer gets is a Jack.

Therefore you have either: a 12, a 22, or a 32.
the computer therefore, keeps the 12 attitude, and adds the jack making it a 22 and loses.

here's the code

```
def evaluateHand(self, dHand):
        DValue = 0

        for card in dHand:
            rank = card.getRank()
            if rank > 10:
                rank = 10
            elif rank == 1 and DValue + 11 <= 21:
                rank = 11
            DValue = DValue + rank


        return DValue
```

here's where i define my value for ace, and i'm pretty sure it's at my elif statement, but nothing else i try works out.
any suggestions?

Comment: small suggestion: change `card.getRank()` to use an property instead, and call it `rank`. Create a new property called `hand_value` that handles the valuation of the card (1-10). Your cards should know how much they're worth, and your hand shouldn't care what their ranks are (except that aces must be special-cased)

Comment: Consider a `card.py` that looks something like [this](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/74d2369f144852141054b9cd11195789)

Answer (score 2):

You can have many aces in a hand, but only one can be valued at 11 without busting.

- First evaluate the value of the hand with aces valued at 1
- Then, if the hand value is < 12 and there is an ace in the hand, value that ace at 11 (add 10 to the hand value)
- Return the correct hand value.

Here is some possible code (with a bit of pseudocode as you did not specify your data structure.)

```
def get_hand_value(self, hand):       
    hand_value = 0
    for card in hand:
        hand_value += card.get_value()      # this evaluates the hand with all aces at 1
    if hand_value < 12 and ace in hand:     # this line is pseudocode, IDK your data structure
                                            # it evaluates one ace (if any) at 11 (if possible w/o busting)
        hand_value += 10
    return hand_value
```

Comment: I've been writing code (and therefore seeing these beginner card game exercises) for over a decade, AND I've moonlit as a professional dealer for 5 or 6 years, and I've NEVER considered approaching this from the bottom up. It should be obvious, but for some reason I've always counted Aces as 11 and subtracted ten instead, which forces me to keep track of *how many* aces there are in the hand (`for _ in range(num_aces): if hand_value > 21: hand_value -= 10`). This is much better.